# 2 iFrame's have to become one

Tags: javascript, iframe, phpgrid

I've got 2 iFrames, but I want to hide one and when a button is clicked I want them to switch. So far there are 2 iFrames but I'll probably need more, way more (like 19). Is it possible to something such as this?

Waiting for your response, and thanks in advance!

- jelmer

Comment: Why don't you change src of iframe when button click `$('#yourframe').attr('src', 'www.someurl.com');`

Comment: The problem is probably with phpGrid. Tried both suggestions.. Doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by hiding all the iframes with css.

```
iframe {
   display:none;     
}
```

In Javascript you set the display of the first IFrame to block and you create a Variable which stores a numeric number which Frame to show (0=first, 1=second, etc)

```
var iframearray = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
iframearray[0].style.display = "block";
var visibleFrame = 0;
```

Then you make a button, with an onClick event.

```
<input type="button" onClick="hideNext" />
```

And at last you make the Javascript function to show the next Frame

```
function hideNext(){
iframearray[visibleFrame ].style.display = "none";
visibleFrame++;
iframearray[visibleFrame ].style.display = "block";
}
```